# DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(Stream stream): Can I read more than one object?

Tags: .net, deserialization

I'm working with .NET 4.0, VS 2010.

I write a file like this:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer btlSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BrainTrackList));
FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(m_fileName);
btlSerializer.WriteObject(fs, trackList);

DataContractJsonSerializer npcemSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(NPCExistsModelData));
npcemSerializer.WriteObject(fs, npcemData);

fs.Close();
fs.Dispose();
```

Which appears to give the result in the text file I expect.

I try to read it with this:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer btlSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BrainTrackList));
BrainTrackList listContainer = (BrainTrackList)btlSerializer.ReadObject(m_stream);

DataContractJsonSerializer npcemSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(NPCExistsModelData));
NPCExistsModelData npceDataContainer = (NPCExistsModelData)npcemSerializer.ReadObject(m_stream);
```

where m_stream is a previously opened Stream object. The btlSerializer returns the object I expect with no trouble, but then m_stream.Position is set to the end of the file, and I can't read the next object. I get an error "Expecting element 'root' from namespace..."

Am I doing something wrong, or do I just need to create an aggregate object to serialize that contains both of the objects? I checked the MSDN documentation on ReadObject to see what it says about its effect on the Stream object, but that page has no information of value on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, this is weird, but apparently I just need to set the stream's position back to the beginning before each call to ReadObject. It is smart enough to ignore everything in the file except the object type I'm trying to read.

So this works:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer btlSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BrainTrackList));
BrainTrackList listContainer = (BrainTrackList)btlSerializer.ReadObject(m_stream);

m_stream.Position = 0;

DataContractJsonSerializer npcemSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(NPCExistsModelData));
NPCExistsModelData npceDataContainer = (NPCExistsModelData)npcemSerializer.ReadObject(m_stream);
```

Comment: I find it odd this wasn't mentioned anywhere in the JsonSerializer docs.

Comment: I also don't know why the Position has to be reset to zero. Thanks.

Comment: The position needs to be reset to Zero because reading from a stream you have just written to will start from its current position, not from the start. This is consistent behaviour with other methods in the framework that read/write to a stream.

Comment: Right. And if the current position is at the end of the JSON object, why doesn't it read the next JSON object afterward?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was because I was using a StreamWriter object and it needed to be flushed.

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Control[]));
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
    sw.Write(data);
```

> sw.Flush();

```
    stream.Position = 0;
    var pfControls = (Control[])ser.ReadObject(stream);
}
```